# Get hyperlinks from RTF byte array

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I have a byte array which represents RTF format. I would like to extract only the hyperlinks from the it. I can extract the plain text using following (but the formatting is lost):

```
Flowdocument doc = new FlowDocument();
TextRange r = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
r.Load(stream, System.Windows.DataFormats.XamlPackage); // stream is MemoryStream. r.Text is the plain text
```

Comment: Can you regex them out, or use a rtf parser maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed data can be found in the Flowdocument & this is general idea of code that will help retrieve it:

```
foreach (Block block in doc.Blocks)
{
  Paragraph p = block as Paragraph;
  foreach (Inline inline in p.Inlines)
  {
    Hyperlink h = inline as Hyperlink;
  }
}
```

Perhaps iterations can be eliminated by RegEx as @TheGeneral suggested. I did find [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b49c7fc-56c9-4ade-ab05-765d8d1d73a9/how-to-find-the-hyperlinks-in-the-pasted-text-in-wpf-richtextbox?forum=wpf) that contains such a RegEx.